# How can I simplify this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc, homework

[image]
My attempt:
I first converted the delta network into a wye network. 
The 4 ohm and 2.69 ohm resistors are in series, that series equivalent is series with the 0.38 ohm and 0.54 ohm resistors. The 3 ohm and 2 ohm resistors are also in series. Finally the 8 ohm and 6 ohm resistor are parallel. Is there an easier way in which I could reduce the circuit keeping the 7 Ohm resistor? If I were to leave the delta network without performing any simplification on it, how can I go about solving this problem?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going delta -> Ys look for Y -> deltas...

[image]